# Update empty column with calculated values from SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, 6 columns, the 6th column is empty but the other 5 have data. I used the 4th and 5th columns to calculate a value and then I wish to insert this value into the 6th column.

This is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE Table_Name 
SET Change = tab3.Difference
FROM
    (SELECT COBDate, FileName, ID, ScenarioID FROM Table_Name WHERE COBDate = '2012-05-18' AND FileName = 'GBP.csv') tab0
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT  tab1.ID, tab1.ScenarioID,tab1.COBDate, tab1.FileName, Val1 - Val2 AS Difference FROM
        (SELECT COBDate, FileName, ScenarioID, ID, CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Value END AS Val1 FROM Table_Name WHERE COBDate = '2012-05-18' AND FileName = 'GBP.csv') tab1
    JOIN
        (SELECT COBDate, FileName, ScenarioID, ID, CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Value END AS Val2  FROM Table_Name WHERE COBDate = '2012-05-17' AND FileName = 'GBP.csv') tab2
    ON tab1.ScenarioID = tab2.ScenarioID AND tab1.ID = tab2.ID) tab3
ON tab0.COBDate = tab3.COBDate
AND tab0.FileName = tab3.FileName
AND tab0.ID = tab3.ID
AND tab0.ScenarioID = tab3.ScenarioID
```

EDIT: The above code hasn't worked. It has set the same value for every single row regardless of the primary key....

Comment: Please post your `SELECT` query too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
UPDATE Table_Name SET Column6 = Column4 + Column5
```

To get the right rows, use a WHERE statement.

Comment: Hi, I found what I needed to do (see edit) but the join isn't quite working. It puts the sam value for every row, rather than the value from tab3

Comment: If you are unsure always do a SELECT first before an UPDATE. Your SELECT will reflect which rows you are about to update, then you can tweak your WHERE clause to get the correct rows and be sure that you aren't messing up your database.

Comment: Hi Charleh, below the SET line I have included SELECT * and when ran with the SQL below it, this shows the value of difference being correct, per row.

Answer (score 0):

Re-write your statement such that the from statement directly references the table that you are updating. For example, remove your first subselect by using a `where` clause, similar to this:

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET Change = tab3.Difference 
FROM Table_Name tab0

    INNER JOIN     

    (SELECT  tab1.ID, tab1.ScenarioID,tab1.COBDate, tab1.FileName, Val1 - Val2 AS Difference 
        FROM
            (SELECT COBDate, FileName, ScenarioID, ID, CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Value END AS Val1 
            FROM Table_Name 
            WHERE COBDate = '2012-05-18' AND FileName = 'GBP.csv'
        ) tab1     
        JOIN         
            (SELECT COBDate, FileName, ScenarioID, ID, CASE WHEN Value IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Value END AS Val2  
            FROM Table_Name 
            WHERE COBDate = '2012-05-17' AND FileName = 'GBP.csv'
        ) tab2 ON 
                tab1.ScenarioID = tab2.ScenarioID 
                AND tab1.ID = tab2.ID
    ) tab3 ON 

    tab0.COBDate = tab3.COBDate 
    AND tab0.FileName = tab3.FileName 
    AND tab0.ID = tab3.ID 
    AND tab0.ScenarioID = tab3.ScenarioID 

WHERE tab0.COBDate = '2012-05-18'
    and tab0.FileName = 'GBP.csv'
```